# Исполнение JS в HTML через google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Работаю в битриксе. Там используются *google* таблицы. При открытии документа, он по умолчанию открывается в новом окне. У окна вечно небольшой экранчик и при работе необходимо его вручную расширять. Хочу на событие `onOpen()` повесить код для увеличения окна на весь экран (ну или настроить на определённые проценты). Копаю в сторону ф-ии `window.open()` на **JS**. Сам я на нынешнем этапе совершенно незнаком с **html** и **JS**. Пытаюсь запустить примерно так:
в `CODE.gs`:

```
function onOpen(){
   void WorkDo();
}
function WorkDo(){
//  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index444'); 
//  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
//      .showSidebar(html);
//  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Example1'));
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Example1');
}
function doSomething(arrg) {
  Browser.msgBox(arrg);
}
```

в `Example1.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      Win2 = window.self;
      Win2.resizeTo(100, 100);
      <!--google.script.run.doSomething(123);-->    
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Почему-то, непосредственно код в **html** выполняется только тогда, когда я выполняю его через `showSidebar`. Не пойму почему.
Ну и собственно, даже если я запускаю его через `Sidebar`, сама настройка размера экрана не происходит. Предполагаю, что `window.self` в этом случае - то окошко `Sidebar`. Поэтому не пойму, как мне так запустить html через само окошко документа, чтобы я смог потом на него сослаться и собственно настроить размеры окна в котором он открылся.
Если это совершенно не правильный путь, скажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сможете получить доступ к изменению размера родительского окна, т.к. скрипты исполняются в своих фреймах на своих хостах. Браузер будет препятствовать доступу к своему API [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

В Таблицах используются [Bound to Google Apps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) скрипты. Таким образом требуется использование [текущего экземпляра интерфейса](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`

#### Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
    void workDo();
}

function workDo() {
    var userInterface = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('app').evaluate();
    // showModelessDialog() - метод расширения текущего ui, такой же как showSidebar()
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'title');
}
```

#### app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var top = window.top;
        console.log(top);
        top.resizeTo(150, 150);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```